# getting the userId back in CustomUserAuthRepository.CreateUserAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, servicestack, servicestack-auth

Being a very basic user of ServiceStack, I tried to give it a go, but several things I can't seem to understand correctly...

I'm using this code in order to use NHibernate as the data layer in the ServiceStack Authentication:

https://gist.github.com/balexandre/f1217ae8e2a2b1045d47

I have modified a bit the `CreateUserAuth` to create a new user in my own table (as I do need more data for the user and the metadata option is not enough), I have extended to this code at line 201:

https://gist.github.com/balexandre/f1217ae8e2a2b1045d47#file-customuserauthrepository-cs-L201

`newUser` is sent back and I do need to get the userId (`newUser.Id`) so I can create a new user in my table with the same userID that UserAuth will have (in order to proper save/edit in the CustomUserSession.cs and populate my user with the logged in information, as shown in several examples).

**How do I get the correct userId?**

I really thought that I could attach the UserAuth object to my custom User like (`newLocalUser.UserAuthInfo`) but I always end up having in the database User.Id == 0

and getting `newUser.Id` after the `Session.Save(new UserAuthNHibernate(newUser))` call, is always `0` as well.

How do you guys attach the new generated UserId of the UserAuth to your own table? or you simply **use the email address for that?**

---

original question is available [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/0sUot3-rBnA).

Comment: Note: in both OrmLite and NHibernate the `Id` is an auto-incrementing id. Are you also using the [UserAuth NHibernate mapping classes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Authentication.NHibernate/UserAuthMap.cs)?

Comment: Yes I am, I have this: http://screencast.com/t/3PjkL2S45NG (changed to `GeneratedBy.GuidNative()` because I could not match the ID's... it was `GeneratedBy.Assigned()` as I was [assigning it here](https://gist.github.com/balexandre/f1217ae8e2a2b1045d47#file-customuserauthrepository-cs-L232) - `UserMap` is the mapping of my custom and needed data (instead of using the meta of `UserAuth` table)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any code in the `CreateUserAuth` method that sets the `newUser.Id` property. Maybe something like...

```
var newUserAuthNhibernate = new UserAuthNHibernate(newUser);
Session.Save(newUserAuthNhibernate);
newUser.Id = newUserAuthNhibernate.Id;
```

is needed? Based on the current code in the gist it looks like NHibernate would set the Id field on a new instance of UserAuthNHibernate created in the `Session.Save()` but I don't see where that Id (which would be generated by DB/NHibernate) would get based back to the current instance of `newUser` that is returned by the `CreateUserAuth` method. Maybe it happens in the UserAuthNHibernate class?

Comment: as said before, after calling `Session.Save(newUserAuthNhibernate);` the `newUserAuthNhibernate` is not yet populated with the `Id`.

Comment: Hm...what database are you using and is the Id column of the UserAuth Table set to auto-increment?